# REGEX Name and any surname

Tags: regex, regex-group, knime

in the example below, I want to make 2 groups in a regex:

Name FirtSurname SecondSurname ..

The first group would be
Name

The second
FirtSurname SecondSurname ...

```
^(\w+)(.*)$   - would capture all
\w+           - would make n groups (number of words).
```

I want only 2 groups. First name and anything that follows on another.

Any help?

Comment: Can you give an example of various inputs you expect to receive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as someone with punctuation in my given name :-) PLEASE don't use `\w` to try to match names :-) … both `-` and `'` are not uncommon.

Using Perl, for example:

```
  if ("Bruce-Robert Fenn Pocock" =~ /^(\w+)(.*)$/) { print "First: $1    Rest: $2" }

  → First: Bruce    Rest: -Robert Fenn Pocock
```

Perhaps just group all non-space characters, then skip the first occurrence of whitespace:

```
  if ("Bruce-Robert Fenn Pocock" =~ /^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/) { print "First: $1    Rest: $2" }

  → First: Bruce-Robert    Rest: Fenn Pocock
```

Of course, if you run across people with *middle* names in your dataset, there's no way to tell them apart from matronym-patronym pairs or multi-part last names.

I hope/assume you don't have honorifics in your input, either.

```
First: Don         Rest: Juan de la Mancha
     *** wrong: Don is honorific
First: Diego       Rest: de la Vega
First: John        Rest: Jacob Smith
     *** wrong: Jacob is probably a middle name
First: De'shawna   Rest: Cummings
First: Wehrner     Rest: von Braun
First: Oscar       Rest: Vazquez-Oliverez
```

Ultimately, the only way to accurately break down a name into an honorific, given name, middle name(s), surnames (matronym, patronym), and suffix(es), is to *ask*.

(EG. my own name, in Anglo circles, the "Fenn" is considered a "middle name," in Latino circles, it's interpreted as a matronym.)

Honorifics and suffices can often be guessed-at from a list, but e.g. military titles and doctoral suffices are a *long* list ("Dr John Doe, Pharm.D", "Maj. Gen. Thomas Ts'o") and not unambiguous (e.g. "Don" is both a short form of "Donald" and an honorific).

### PS. Lovely article here:

http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only a single space between words, this works:

```
(\w+) ([\w ]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lz_fXin6KIxgPL5e)

If multiple spaces are a possibility:

```
(\w+) +([\w ]+)
```

To eliminate the spaces at the ends:

```
\b(\w+)\b \b([\w ]+)\b
```

To allow dashes and apostrophes, as mentioned by @BRPocock:

```
\b([\w-']+)\b \b([\w -']+)\b
```

While this forbids punctuation at the ends, it allows multiple dashes and apostrophes, including next to each other, such as: `Mc'er'''doo--dl-e`

Making it more robust than this can become a project within itself.

Comment: Ack!! You accepted my answer and then unaccepted it!!  `X(`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want the first name in group 1 and the rest of the name in group 2:

`^(\b[\w]+\b)([\w\W]+)`